# 500 Internal server error .htaccess

Tags: apache

The below given .htaccess code is fetching internal error

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([w]{3,3}[.]{1,1}){0,1}example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)[.]example.com$
RewriteRule ^$ portfolio/index.php?id=%1 [NC,L]

AuthType Basic
AuthName "If your not authenticated , then go seat in corner"
AuthUserFile /var/www/devRoot/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

But if i am using only

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "If your not authenticated , then go seat in corner"
AuthUserFile /var/www/devRoot/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

above code is working perfect.

Issue is i am not able understand why the 1st code is not working .

Logs :

```
[Wed Jul 10 13:12:11 2013] [alert] [client 1.23.112.242] /var/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configur                             ation
[Wed Jul 10 13:12:12 2013] [alert] [client 1.23.112.242] /var/www/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configur                             ation
```

solved :

```
Did you ensure the RewriteEngine is on?

You'll want to verify that the mod is enabled - just look for rewrite.load symlink in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled. If not, run sudo a2enmod rewrite to enable it. Restart apache using sudo service apache2 restart and provided your .htaccess syntax is correct this will work.

Otherwise you will need to paste more information about your .htaccess file.
```

Comment: Start with turning ON debug logging. Then consider superuser.com instead..

Comment: how i can turn ON debugging

Answer (score 0):

you havent enabled the rewrite engine, uncomment the line in httpd.conf

```
LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

You may have it in /etc/apache2/mods-available in which case just copy it to mods-enabled and restart

thats assuming linux ?

windows you looking for

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Comment: Did you ensure the RewriteEngine is on?

You'll want to verify that the mod is enabled - just look for rewrite.load symlink in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled. If not, run sudo a2enmod rewrite to enable it. Restart apache using sudo service apache2 restart and provided your .htaccess syntax is correct this will work.

Otherwise you will need to paste more information about your .htaccess file.